# useEffect não reconhece novo valor

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-hooks

O hook useEffect dispara quando alguma variável no seu array atualiza. No entanto, quando o valor da variável continua o mesmo, o hook simplesmente ignora.

Esse hook recebe um valor e da um push no array que está no useState.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setDataUser(dataUser => [...dataUser, afterAttackUser]);
}, [afterAttackUser]);
```

Porém se o valor de `afterAttackUser` for 4, por exemplo, e receber 4 novamente, é como se o valor da váriavel não mudasse, então o useEffect não dispara.. Mas eu preciso colocar essa valor dentro do array...
Alguma luz para proceder? criei algumas lógicas mas sem sucesso.

edit: Bom eu quero renderizar os valores do array num map que vai retonar um Text.

componente inteiro:

```
export default function CombatLog() {
  const afterAttackUser = useSelector(state => state.combatReducer.afterAttack);
  const currentEnemyLife = useSelector(state => state.currentEnemyInfoReducer.currentLife);
  const maxEnemyLife = useSelector(state => state.currentEnemyInfoReducer.maxLife);

  const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState(Array);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setDataUser(dataUser => [...dataUser, afterAttackUser]);
    console.log(`tamanho do array: ${dataUser.length}`);
  }, [afterAttackUser]);

  return(
    <ImageBackground style={styles.container} resizeMode='stretch' source={Img}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Registro do Combate</Text>
      <View>
        {
          dataUser.map((damage, index) => {      
            if(damage != 1)
              return <Text style={styles.textUser} key={index}>Você infligiu {damage} de dano</Text>
          })
        }
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Comment: você tem como colocar aonde você atualizar, só `useEffect` eu não consigo dizer o porque disso, ou seja, coloque o componente inteiro !

Comment: explique também o funcionamento desejado na sua pergunta fala fala e não explica (entenda queremos chegar no mesmo ponto mas, falta informação)

Comment: foi mal, atualizei agora brother

Comment: Amigo, seguinte a variável é um ContextApi ou Redux certo: ela só sofre alteração mediante algum evento, cade o evento, a função algo assim? não atualiza mesmo.

Comment: Ta em outro arquivo, e ta disparando muito bem. o problema é que o useEffect nao dispara quando o valor da variavel continua o mesmo, eu só preciso de uma lógica para passar disso. já tentei inumeras..

Comment: Então, como funciona esse useEffect como você citou, só vai executar quando o valor for alterado o que você pretende fazer talvez a solução é outra (quase certeza)

Comment: Você não pode atualizar a nível do redux/context mesmo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar retornar um objeto onde uma das propriedades seria a `afterAttack` e outra uma com valor randômico como identificação que muda a cada atualização de `afterAttack`.

Dessa forma, mesmo que `afterAttack` retorne o mesmo valor, o `useEffect` será executado com alteração da propriedade randômica.

Algo como:

```js
export default function CombatLog() {
  /* No seu reducer, adicione um valor randômico em `afterAttackId` para cada atualização de `afterAttack` */
  const { afterAttack, afterAttackId } = useSelector(state => state.combatReducer);
  const currentEnemyLife = useSelector(state => state.currentEnemyInfoReducer.currentLife);
  const maxEnemyLife = useSelector(state => state.currentEnemyInfoReducer.maxLife);

  const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState(Array);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setDataUser(dataUser => [...dataUser, afterAttack]);
    console.log(`tamanho do array: ${dataUser.length}`);
  /* use `afterAttackId` para identificar a mudança` */
  }, [afterAttackId]);

  return(
    <ImageBackground style={styles.container} resizeMode='stretch' source={Img}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Registro do Combate</Text>
      <View>
        {
          dataUser.map((damage, index) => {      
            if(damage != 1)
              return <Text style={styles.textUser} key={index}>Você infligiu {damage} de dano</Text>
          })
        }
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Tenta ai